# Why is my form not submitting POST value?

Tags: php, forms

I am creating this simple page that will handle log in and registration requests, but for some reason, my form is not submitting my one post value.

PHP

```
session_start();

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(isset($_SESSION["sid"])) {
    $sid = $_SESSION["sid"];

} else {
    if(isset($_GET['login'])){
        $code = MySQLConnection::login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $ip);
        /**
         * Login Error codes
         * ______________________________________________
         * |   0    |        EVERY THING IS OK          |
         * |--------+-----------------------------------|
         * |   1    |          No Such User             |
         * |--------+-----------------------------------|
         * |   2    |         Incorrect Pass            |
         * |--------+-----------------------------------|
         * |   3    |        Error Signing in           |
         * |--------------------------------------------|
         */
        switch($code) {
            case 0:
                header("Location: ControlCenter.php");
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
                header("Location: index.html?error=1");
                break;
            case 3:
                header("Location: index.html?error=2");
                break;
        }
    } else if(isset($_GET['register'])){
        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
            MySQLConnection::register($_POST['email']);
            echo("success");
        } else {
            echo("Email not submitted");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="authenticator3000.php?register">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="email" required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
```

the error occurs before the register function, because when run, "Email not submitted" is echo'd.

without the if statement checking if POST is set I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: email
```

I am not sure where my problem lies because the value of email will be submitted with method="get". I have another form in the page for logging users in, and everything gets submitted there.

HTML for login:

```
<form action="authenticator3000.php?login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="email" required="required"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="password" required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

Every value gets submitted and works correctly. I even re-copied and pasted my code from login to the register area, and changed the ?login to ?register.

As far as I can tell, there is no syntax errors.

### Update

I just tested out the var_dump on the login part, and found that $_POST was empty there too.

Comment: is `enable_post_data_reading` disabled in your `php.ini` by any chance? Have you checked server logs?

Comment: @Kisaragi my php.ini reads ";enable_post_data_reading = Off"

Comment: @Shifty16: Can you please share entire `authenticator3000.php` script. Same script handles both login and registration request, but we see only registration part.

Snippets that you posted look just fine, so problem could be somewhere else in the script. :)

Comment: @MladenIlić I updated the PHP to show relevent info.  The only thing I removed was the half finished session ID verification

Answer (score 0):

My server was misconfigured.  I am not sure exactly why but I used a different server and everything worked fine.  Thank you for your helps